# Facing problem calling my date service in my homepage.ts ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular7

so i am using firebase annd ionic to get list of notes in my fire base db but whwn i try to retrieve them i get the

error  in my home-page.html  src/app/home/home.page.ts:19:12 - error TS7006: Parameter 'note' implicitly has an 'any' type.

19   openNote(note) {

my  home-page.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../services/data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  notes = [];

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.getNotes().subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.notes = res;
    });
  }

  openNote(note) {

  }
}
```

my data.serve.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  collectionData,
  deleteDoc,
  doc,
  docData,
  Firestore,
  updateDoc
} from "@angular/fire/firestore";

import {Observable} from "rxjs";

export interface Note {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  text: string;
}
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  constructor(private firestore: Firestore) { }

  getNotes(): Observable<Note[]> {
    const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, 'notes');
    return collectionData(notesRef, {idField: 'id'}) as Observable<Note[]>;
  }

  getNoteById(id:string): Observable<Note> {
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `notes/${id}`);
    return docData(noteDocRef, {idField: 'id'}) as Observable<Note>;
  }

  addNote(note: Note) {
    const notesRef = collection(this.firestore, 'notes');
    return addDoc(notesRef, note);
  }

  deleteNote(note: Note) {
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `notes/${note.id}`);
    return deleteDoc(noteDocRef);
  }

  updateNote(note: Note) {
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `notes/${note.id}`);
    return updateDoc(noteDocRef, {title: note.title, text: note.text});
  }
}
```

my home.html

```
<ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Farm Crud
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

<ion-item *ngFor="let note of notes" (click)="openNote(note)" )>
    <ion-label>
   {{note.name}}
    </ion-label>

</ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

where there are errors

```
  this.notes = res;
```

```
  openNote(note) {

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a model for your notes array.

```
notes: Note[] = [];


export interface Note {
  name: string;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your tsconfig.json file set the parameter "noImplicitAny": false under compilerOptions to get rid of this error.

Otherwise specify the type  openNote(note : any) or whatever type you are using